Where can I find information on and examples of the RLC (relocating loader) format for the TRS-80 Model 100?
According to this wiki page:

RLC is a representation of an 8085 machine language program that is relocatable and 7-bit clean.
There are many programs in the Compuserve Model 100 SIG archive, for example, that are formatted as RLC files.

It continues on to say that the format uses only the characters 0123456789:;<=>?, and a start address (not included in the file) must be supplied at load time. It gives some further information on the format related to the header, length, data, relocation offsets (an @ followed by a "a big-endian, base-16 representation of an address to be relocated") and a checksum that is "is at least a 32-bit integer" in decimal format.
What I'm looking for is:

Any original (or at least earlier) documentation on this format.
One or more loader programs (preferably with source) that read this format and enter the program into the memory of a Model 100 computer (or any other similar machine).
Programs originally distributed in this format, along with any accompanying documentation on how to transfer them to a Model 100 and do a relocating load of them.

If none of the above can be found, it would be helpful at least to have personal recollections of the use of this format and how it worked, to help confirm the information in the wiki page linked above.

Partial answer:
I quickly googled for "Compuserve Model 100 SIG archive", found this on archive.org, and the RLC files it contains look e.g. like (Lib-04-APPS/CAL.RLC):
 3341  0 
<=@0;722163?922@0<722:@0<72>;2101001922@0<7021@049;22@0<6>2:@0<72>;210100>;424;087>6?2600>;21<000<=@0;>87<;5<2@009><=@0892
<=@0:722:@0<70>;2:@0<72=5>;21060019=1<=@0<007<;5<:@00872:@0<72>;210100>;424;0822@0<6<2:@0<72>;210100197>6?2600>;210001<=
...
1?151=011=031?151?07051?17151=1?101?1?061?1?111?011?011?101?1?0<1?1?1511011?011?041?1?05011?091617151=1>051>
 1800190 

So "3341 0" is the header, "1800190" is the checksum, obviously in decimal. Given that there are 16 characters, the obvious guess is the each encodes a nibble, and the wiki page indeed says "The high nibble appears first.".
The header is described on the wiki page:

The first line starts with (in ASCII format) the number of bytes in the RLC file, followed by the offset within the image to the entry point.

It explains relocation offsets in the body:

A relocation offset is represented by an '@' sign and followed by a big-endian, base-16 representation of an address to be relocated. Example: @035>

and the checksum:

The checksum is the arithmetic sum of all offsets and octets in the image. It is at least a 32-bit integer.

So I guess that's a complete description. The loader is described in Lib-07-UTILITIES/RLCLDR.DOC in the archive. Writing a new one should also be a simple exercise.
